# jquery ordena meu data automaticamente

Tags: jquery, json

Eu gero um json em uma url qualquer, como este:

```
{"130":"chocolate","129":"banana","120":"chiclete"}
```

dai vou buscar com $.get

```
$.get(url,function(data){
   console.debug(data);
},'json');
```

resultado ( ele ordena automaticamente, sem eu precisar):

```
Object { 120="chiclete", 129="banana", 130="banana"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Em JavaScript, objetos são **conjuntos** de pares chave/valor. Conjuntos, por definição, não têm ordem. `{1,2,3} == {1,3,2} == {2,1,3}` etc. Na hora de imprimir no console, se escolhe arbitrariamente uma ordem (que, no caso, foi em ordem crescente das chaves), mas isso não quer dizer que o objeto está ordenado de fato, nem que em todas as situações a ordem de iteração/uso/impressão será a mesma.

Se você *realmente precisa* de uma ordem definida - seja a ordem em que o servidor enviou, seja uma ordenação qualquer definida por você via JavaScript - então não use objetos, use arrays de arrays:

```
[["130","chocolate"],["129","banana"],["120","chiclete"]]
```

Caso contrário, o browser pode e vai mudar a ordem [de uso] como bem entender.